# Controlled from in React

Tags: javascript, reactjs, frontend, web-deployment, use-state

I'm new in react and I'm a bit confused about how React runs update on every new input's keystroke, for exapmpe, this is the form and I want to update the state on every keystroke

```
import React, {useState} from 'react';

let FormsPractice =()=>{
let  [data, updateData] =useState('')
  
 let handleChange =(event)=>{

     let {value} = event.target;
       
     updateData(value)
     }

    return(
        <div className ="container">
            <form >
                <input
                        type="text"
                        placeholder="Enter name"
                        name="name"
                        value={data}
                        onChange={handleChange}
                />
            
            </form>
        </div>
    )
}
export default FormsPractice
```

What I don't understand here is the update cycle, my understanding is the following:

As the input's value is tied to react state, the initial value of the input is obviously "".

Now I come to the point:

=> when a keystorke happens, let's suppose an "a" character is typed;

=> the handleChange method is invoked;

=> event.target.value, does it retrun "a" (as a value of the input's own state) or does it return empty, because the value is tied to the state (value={data} I'm not sure what state is assigned to the value in this case)
Hope I can understand this

Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The **onChange** event handler is a prop that you can pass to  `<input>` elements. and it listens to user input in real time.

whenever you type something into the input, React will trigger the function that you passed into the `onChange` which calls the function you passed as its parameter. in your case you're calling  `handleChange` . The event object passed into handleChange function contains all the detail about the input event.

**in your case** when  you type 'a' in the input react will trigger   `handleChange`  this function update the state from **data = ""** and `value={data} ==> value=""`  to **data="a"** `value={data} ==> value="a"`